# How to avoid the bug of transition opacity for vertical svg line in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, svg, css-transitions

I created a very simple vertical line with `stroke-width: 1px` and `shape-rendering: crispEdges`. When I tried to animate its opacity, it turned out that Google Chrome v62.0.3202.89 (64 bit) failed to render it properly, while other browsers (such as IE11, Edge, current versions of Firefox and Opera) do it correctly.

How do we avoid this erratic behavior before it is fixed in Chrome?

Comment: If you have found a bug in Chrome. You should report it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, reported it.

Comment: Thanks!  Can you post the link here for future reference please?

Comment: I sent the report via Chrome feedback form, so I got no link or reference for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created this simple example https://codepen.io/ch3rn0v/pen/ZaypbW?editors=0110 to demonstrate three options for work-arounds, even though none of them if perfect.

Personally I think the one that makes the line not absolutely vertical is the best in terms of visual appearance, yet the knowledge that it is not purely vertical bothers me.

```
const notSoVerticalLineCoords = {
    x1: lineOffsetX + 2 * lineHorizontalOffset + 0.01,
    x2: lineOffsetX + 2 * lineHorizontalOffset,
    y1: lineTopOffsetY,
    y2: lineLength + lineTopOffsetY
};
```